# Decrease time searching images in folder

Tags: php, performance, directory

I've built a site in PHP, where the user can choose which image folder that they want to see. There's more than one folder and each folder have more than 10,000 images.

However, I simply want to find the newest image in each folder, but this is taking a very long time. How can I speed this up?

**Edit**

```
$file = new GlobIterator($d.'*.jpg', FilesystemIterator::KEY_AS_FILENAME);
foreach ($file as $f) {
    $files[] = $d.$f->getFilename();
}
sort($files, SORT_NATURAL | SORT_FLAG_CASE);
$path = end($files);
return $path;
```

Comment: taking long? for what image load or on option select??

Comment: Can you please update your question with the PHP code that you're using to scan the image folder. Without this, it's impossible to tell what you're doing and hence advise on how you could improve the speed of operation.

Comment: @swapnesh for image load

Answer (score 1):

Instead of scanning each directory in real-time (I'm guessing this is what you're doing - it's hard to tell due to the paucity of information in your question), you could avoid this speed issue if you store meta information on each image in a database (including the path to the file on disk - don't store the actual image in the database).

By doing this, you'll be able to carry out high-speed searches based on criteria such as last added, etc. as long as you have the necessary fields/the appropriate indexes set.

N.B.: It's important to ensure that the database and filesystem are keep in sync, so ensure that delete operations are carried out via your code (which would remove both the database record and the file on disk).